# Get Facebook Page Offers that haven't Expired via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook Page. I am trying to get the Non Expired 'Offers' that exist from the Pages that my Page Likes.

This is what I use to get all the offers (Including Expired):

GRAPH GET (2.5): /210111832375724/likes?fields=offers

(210111832375724 is my page ID)

I have used 'since(now)', but it failed. It seems to work for events, but not offers.

I could just get all offers and then use my software to select ones that haven't expired, but thought I would see if there is a better solution.

Comment: My first ever question, I scoured the internet for hours for a solution first, I wrote the question well, and explained it well, and the first thing I get is down voted. As a new member to this community, and ideas why? I would be happy to fix things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the Facebook docs, I don't see another possibility then to filter the "valid" ones from the Graph API call's response. There is currently no general way to filter results in the Graph API.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/offers/#Reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/offer

Comment: Thanks Tobi. Made me feel better.  I ended up collecting them all and then using php just used an if statement to remove old ones. In the future there might be a better solution like the 'since'. Cheers.